# How to Use the Java Compiler Replay File to debug JVM Issues

Tags: java, jit, segmentation-fault

I have a Java server process that is now intermittently crashing with the following crash report:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f8c169f6df8, pid=33597, tid=140237357057792
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_40-b25) (build 1.8.0_40-b25)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.40-b25 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# V  [libjvm.so+0x404df8]  PhaseChaitin::gather_lrg_masks(bool)+0x208
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# / blah2/hs_err_pid33597.log
#
# Compiler replay data is saved as:
# /blah2/replay_pid33597.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
#
```

Before I think of effecting any machine configuration changes (such as changing the VM flags passed in or adding additional logging of any kind), I would like to perform as much analysis of whatever diagnostic information is available.

Does the replay_pid file have information that can help me (as an application developer) diagnose this problem or is it for VM crash reporting to Oracle? Are there any tools available that can analyze it (similar to a thread dump analyzer for instance)?

Any help/hints appreciated.

Thanks
AD

Answer (score 4):

Yes, the replay file can help you to reproduce the issue in a controlled manner.

There's an excellent presentation "Analyzing HotSpot Crashes" by Volker Simonis which covers this - here's a direct link to the relevant example in that talk: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xC8fEeo7izI&feature=youtu.be&t=1888